# How did the import statement find that module?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

Given the following directory structure:

```
here/
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── json.py
│   └── example.py
└── my_script.py
```

`__init__.py` and `json.py` are empty files.

Contents of `my_script.py`:

```
from app import example
```

Contents of `example.py`

```
import importlib, imp, sys, os

# ensures '' is not in sys.path
sys.path = [p for p in sys.path if p]

# ensures PYTHONPATH, if any, is not over-reaching
os.environ.pop('PYTHONPATH', None)

# ensures we do not see json.py in the cwd
assert not os.path.isfile('json.py')

print '1: ', imp.find_module('json')
print '2: ', __import__('json')
print '3: ', importlib.import_module('json')

import json
json.loads
```

Now, from the `here` directory, execute:

```
python ./my_script.py
```

You will see that methods 1, 2, 3, all find the core library version of `json` module.

However, the actual import statement still manages to grab the empty `json.py` file somehow (`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'loads'`).

My understanding was that the package version of json here should have only been accessible by namespace, i.e. `from app import json`, but the namespacing doesn't seem to work here.

On python3, I can not reproduce the issue.  I also noticed if we put `from __future__ import absolute_import` into the `example.py` file, the problem just goes away.

How does the import statement find the local file, and why does it shadow the core library version?

*edit:* on another minor note, by the time we have reached the line `import json`, there is already a json module loaded into `sys.modules` from the lines above.  So why does python try to import the module again, shouldn't it simply use the one already in the module cache?

Comment: You are not calling __import__ correctly. Try adding this line to your example.py: `print '4: ', __import__('json', globals(), locals(), [], -1)`

Comment: @hruske that makes no difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have more or less arrived at the answer here. Python 2.x by default will do a package-relative import first, which includes the potential of "shadowing" a base-level package.

See the section on [Intra-package References](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references) in the python 2 documentation.

The ability to specify explicit relative imports, as well as `from __future__ import absolute_import`, were actually introduced back in Python 2.5 and this is explained further in [PEP 328](https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-328.html). This behavior became the default in Python 3. The new behavior (assumed absolute and explicit relative imports) was implemented in large part explicitly to address the problem you raise (shadowing builtin modules) although it also allows greater control with multi-level relative import syntax (i.e. `..` for the parent module, `...` for a level further up, and so on.)

Comment: Where is it documented that python 2.7 will do a "package-relative import"?  I can not find that.

Comment: In the documentation for modules, at least https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: it says "When a module named spam is imported, the interpreter first searches for a built-in module with that name. If not found, it then searches for a file named spam.py"